# SQL QUERY----Retrieve all email

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$q="SELECT DISTINCT 
            t1.un_email,t6.email
                   FROM
                   sisters_7sisters.tbl_unsubscribe as  t1,
                   sisters_7sisters.tbl_uptade_list as t6";
```

I write a query like above I need to retrieve all the unique emails from the tables 
But it gives me pair of some results which are not unique ..I tried to get the email only once
from these tables.

Comment: @TheJumpingFrog: Have you read the query. He is using `DISTINCT`?

Comment: You forgot some where-clause? You have to join the two tables logically

Comment: @Arion Ah, yeah, noticed it after I commented. Normally, I use all column names in a single line, so didn't notice it at first.

Comment: I have no condition to write where clause

Comment: Do you need it in two column? Or are you fine with one?

Comment: Why no Condition? Can you combine the two tables like t1.username = t6.username or something else? If not, you can use two selects and combine the two selects with UNION or UNION ALL

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a join to join those two tables and select the distinct email

The distinct you are using, is only applied to each column of the result and not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It you are not joing them and you do not have any `where` clause. Then you might be fine with this solution (No duplicate emails):

```
SELECT
    t1.un_email AS email
FROM
    sisters_7sisters.tbl_unsubscribe as t1
UNION
SELECT
    t6.email
FROM
    sisters_7sisters.tbl_uptade_list as t6
```

Or you can use a `UNION ALL`. This will return the duplicates:

```
SELECT
    t1.un_email AS email
FROM
    sisters_7sisters.tbl_unsubscribe as t1
UNION
SELECT
    t6.email
FROM
    sisters_7sisters.tbl_uptade_list as t6
```

Comment: or maybe UNION ALL instead of UNION

Comment: I was just thinking. If he wants all the unique emails. Then a `UNION ALL` will return the duplicates also. I will update the answer to have a `UNION ALL` as well. So the OP can choose for himself

Answer (score 0):

Ithink you have forgot Join ocndition

when you use

```
select * from table1,table2
```

it will create a [cartisian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

if table1 as

```
1

2

3
```

and table2 has

4

5

6

as their data.

cartesian product will be

```
1 4

1 5

1 6

2 4

2 5

2 6

3 4

3 5

3 6
```

to remove this unnecesary fields
you have to [Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)